# Pixi.js viewport follow object

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm making a simple game where a user walks around with a person. The person's gun will always be pointing the mouse. What I want is to allow the person to walk outside the viewport, with the viewport adapting to this. The viewport should always have the person in the middle. I already tried [this library](https://github.com/davidfig/pixi-viewport), but I couldn't get it to work. A good example of what I mean is Agar.io, where the player always sees himself in the middle of the viewport, and everything around him moves.

Does anyone have a clue how I should do this with Pixi.js?

My code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
      <style>
          canvas{border:2px solid #000;}
      </style>
</head>
<script src="pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyboard(value) {
        let key = {};
        key.value = value;
        key.isDown = false;
        key.isUp = true;
        key.press = undefined;
        key.release = undefined;
        //The `downHandler`
        key.downHandler = event => {
            if (event.key === key.value) {
                if (key.isUp && key.press) key.press();
                key.isDown = true;
                key.isUp = false;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        };

        //The `upHandler`
        key.upHandler = event => {
            if (event.key === key.value) {
                if (key.isDown && key.release) key.release();
                key.isDown = false;
                key.isUp = true;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        };

        //Attach event listeners
        const downListener = key.downHandler.bind(key);
        const upListener = key.upHandler.bind(key);

        window.addEventListener(
            "keydown", downListener, false
        );
        window.addEventListener(
            "keyup", upListener, false
        );

        // Detach event listeners
        key.unsubscribe = () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", downListener);
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", upListener);
        };
        return key;
    }
    //Aliases
    let Application = PIXI.Application,
        loader = PIXI.loader,
        resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
        Sprite = PIXI.Sprite;

    //Create a Pixi Application
    let app = new Application();
    app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;

    //Add the canvas that Pixi automatically created for you to the HTML document
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);

    //load an image and run the `setup` function when it's done
    loader
        .add([
            "sprite.png",
            "img/walking/walking1.png",
            "img/walking/walking2.png"
        ])
        .load(setup);

    let alienImages = ["img/walking/walking1.png","img/walking/walking2.png","img/walking/walking3.png","img/walking/walking4.png","img/walking/walking5.png","img/walking/walking6.png","img/walking/walking7.png","img/walking/walking8.png"];
    let textureArray = [];

    for (let i=0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        let texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(alienImages[i]);
        textureArray.push(texture);
    };

    console.log(textureArray);

    let cat;
    let pixie = new PIXI.MovieClip(textureArray);
    let radian;
    let radianLast;
    let mouseX;
    let mouseY;
    let left = keyboard("a"),
        up = keyboard("w"),
        right = keyboard("d"),
        down = keyboard("s");

    function checkIfAnimationStop(){
        if(!right.isDown && !left.isDown && !down.isDown && !up.isDown){
            pixie.gotoAndStop(0);
        }
    }

    //This `setup` function will run when the image has loaded
    function setup() {
        //Create the cat sprite
        cat = new Sprite(resources["sprite.png"].texture);
        //cat.anchor.set(84.5, 115.5);
        pixie.vx = 0;
        pixie.vy = 0;

        //Add the cat to the stage
        pixie.position.set(32, 32);
        app.stage.addChild(pixie);
        pixie.animationSpeed = 0.2;

        left.press = () => {
            //Change the cat's velocity when the key is pressed
            pixie.play();
            pixie.vx = -4;
        };

        //Left arrow key `release` method
        left.release = () => {
            //If the left arrow has been released, and the right arrow isn't down,
            //and the cat isn't moving vertically:
            //Stop the cat
            if (!right.isDown) {
                pixie.vx = 0;
            }
            left.isDown = false;
            checkIfAnimationStop();
        };

        //Up
        up.press = () => {
            pixie.play();
            pixie.vy = -4;
        };
        up.release = () => {
            if (!down.isDown) {
                pixie.vy = 0;
            }
            up.isDown = false;
            checkIfAnimationStop();
        };

        //Right
        right.press = () => {
            pixie.play();
            pixie.vx = 4;
        };
        right.release = () => {
            if (!left.isDown) {
                pixie.vx = 0;
            }
            right.isDown = false;
            checkIfAnimationStop();
        };

        //Down
        down.press = () => {
            pixie.play();
            pixie.vy = 4;
        };
        down.release = () => {
            if (!up.isDown) {
                pixie.vy = 0;
            }
            down.isDown = false;
            checkIfAnimationStop();
        };

        pixie.rotation = 0.5;

        state = play;

        app.ticker.add(delta => gameLoop(delta));
    }

    function gameLoop(delta){
        state(delta);

    }

    function play(delta){
        pixie.anchor.x = 0.9;
        pixie.anchor.y = 0.5;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            mouseX = e.pageX;
            mouseY = e.pageY;
            radianLast = radian;
        });
        radian = Math.atan2(mouseX-pixie.x,-(mouseY-pixie.y));
        if((radian - pixie.rotation) > 0){
            if((radian - pixie.rotation) > 3.14){
                pixie.rotation -= 0.05;
                if(pixie.rotation < -3.1){
                    pixie.rotation = 3.13;
                }
            } else {
                pixie.rotation += 0.05;
            }
        }
        if((radian - pixie.rotation) < 0){
            if((radian - pixie.rotation) < -3.14){
                pixie.rotation += 0.05;
                if(pixie.rotation > 3.1){
                    pixie.rotation = -3.13;
                }
            } else {
                pixie.rotation -= 0.05;
            }
        }
        $("#angle").text(pixie.vx);
        $("#info").text(pixie.vy);
        if(pixie.vx != 0 && pixie.vy != 0){
            if(pixie.vx > 0){
                pixie.vx2 = 2.828;
            } else if(pixie.vx < 0){
                pixie.vx2 = -2.828;
            }
            if(pixie.vy > 0){
                pixie.vy2 = 2.828;
            } else if(pixie.vy < 0){
                pixie.vy2 = -2.828;
            }
            pixie.x += pixie.vx2;
            pixie.y += pixie.vy2;
            $("#angle").text(pixie.vx2);
            $("#info").text(pixie.vy2);
        } else {
            pixie.x += pixie.vx;
            pixie.y += pixie.vy;
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="angle"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="t"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://davidfig.github.io/pixi-viewport/jsdoc/Follow.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a container to act as your world.
2. Place your sprites in the container
3. When you move your player, update the *pivot* of the container

```js
    const world = new PIXI.Container();
    
    world.height = 4000;

    world.width = 4000;
    
    world.x = app.screen.width / 2;

    world.y = app.screen.height / 2;

    world.pivot.x = world.width / 2;

    world.pivot.y = world.height / 2;

    //create sprites

    world.addChild(sprite3);

    world.addChild(sprite2);
    
    world.addChild(player);

    app.stage.addChild(world);

    app.ticker.add((delta) => {
      let distance = delta * 10;
      if(Input.Left) { //Get player input however you please
        player.x -= distance;
        world.pivot.x = player.x;
      }
      else if (Input.Right) {
        player.x += distance;
        world.pivot.x = player.x;
      }
    });
```

You might need to tweak some placement, etc to line things up correctly, but this is the general idea.